# What's the difference between interpreted and uninterpreted function in Z3?

Tags: z3

While reading *Fast LCF-style proof reconstruction for Z3* I read that there are interpreted functions like + or forall in Z3's language. I guess there are also uninterpreted functions. What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are functions that have a name and signature but no definition, see [Uninterpreted Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterpreted_function).